# C# Linq Groupby and Where

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a custom list, shown below.

```
class ActionToDo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime dtDate {get;set;}
    public string EventCode {get;set;}
    public string EventDescription {get;set;}
}
```

What I would like to do is find items which have the same date & same event description and where the `EventCode = "AQ"`. I am guessing `LINQ` is the best way to achieve this? I do not know how to do this though using `LINQ`.

In my head using `Sql` I think it would roughly be something like below.

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE [EventDescription] = 'AQ'
GROUP BY [dtDate], [EventDescription]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Where(x=> x.EventDescription == "AQ")
.GroupBy(x => new { x.dtDate.Date, x.EventDescription})
```

Answer (score 2):

So let's assume you have a

```
List<ActionToDo> actionToDo = new List<ActionToDo>();
actionToDo.Where(i => i.EventDescription == "AQ" && i.EventCode="AQ")
.GroupBy(i => new { i.dtDate.Date, i.EventDescription });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a LINQ query expressed using **query syntax** that meets your requirements. In addition, it also sorts the grouping properties `dtDate` and `EventDescription` and then the members of each group by `Name`:

```
var actions = new List<ActionToDo>();
// populate 'actions'

var results =
    from a in actions
    where a.EventCode == "AQ"
    orderby a.dtDate, a.EventDescription, a.Name
    group a by new { a.dtDate, a.EventDescription };
```

To demonstrate this query, I created a program with some sample `ActionToDo` data in random order. Please see below for the formatted output from the program followed by the program itself.

**Demonstration Program Output**

```
[2014-02-12] [Desc.AQ.12]
  AQ.12a
  AQ.12b
[2014-02-13] [Desc.AQ.13]
  AQ.13a
  AQ.13b
  AQ.13c
[2014-02-14] [Desc.AQ.14]
  AQ.14a
  AQ.14b
```

**Demonstration Program**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class GroupByDemo
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var actions = new List<ActionToDo>()
            {
                new ActionToDo("AQ.14b", "2014-02-14", "AQ", "Desc.AQ.14"),
                new ActionToDo("AQ.12a", "2014-02-12", "AQ", "Desc.AQ.12"),
                new ActionToDo("AQ.13b", "2014-02-13", "AQ", "Desc.AQ.13"),
                new ActionToDo("XX.01",  "2014-02-01", "XX", "Desc.XX.01"),
                new ActionToDo("AQ.14a", "2014-02-14", "AQ", "Desc.AQ.14"),
                new ActionToDo("AQ.12b", "2014-02-12", "AQ", "Desc.AQ.12"),
                new ActionToDo("AQ.13a", "2014-02-13", "AQ", "Desc.AQ.13"),
                new ActionToDo("XX.02",  "2014-02-02", "XX", "Desc.XX.02"),
                new ActionToDo("AQ.13c", "2014-02-13", "AQ", "Desc.AQ.13"),
                new ActionToDo("XX.03",  "2014-02-03", "XX", "Desc.XX.03")
            };

        var results =
            from a in actions
            where a.EventCode == "AQ"
            orderby a.dtDate, a.EventDescription, a.Name
            group a by new { a.dtDate, a.EventDescription };

        foreach (var group in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] [{1}]",
                              group.Key.dtDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                              group.Key.EventDescription);

            foreach (var action in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}", action.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ActionToDo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime dtDate {get;set;}
    public string EventCode {get;set;}
    public string EventDescription {get;set;}

    public ActionToDo(
        string name,
        string dtDateString,
        string eventCode,
        string eventDescription)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.dtDate = DateTime.Parse(dtDateString);
        this.EventCode = eventCode;
        this.EventDescription = eventDescription;
    }
}
```